# The use of the phrase after 'associated with'

Tags: word-usage

*"People either experiencing their second infection, being immuno-suppressed, or being around the age of 15 is likely to be associated with the occurence of dengue haemorrhagic fever."*

In this sentence, I'm confused with the use of the phrase 'the occurence of dengue haemorrhagic fever' after 'associated with'. I found the sentence in a test question.
I think it is something wrong. Please explain it to me.
The occurence of dengue haemorrhagic fever is likely to be associated with those either experiencing their second infection, being immuno-suppressed, or being around the age of 15. I'd like to know whether the second sentence has the same meaning with the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the cause of the  "second infection"  is probably "connected to/related to"  the presence of dengue haemmoragic  fever.

Comment: Thanks, Absolute Beginner. Do you mean that ' A is associated with B' is the same as 'B is associated with A'?

Comment: It means that the Aand B are somehow related, the nature and the extent of the relashionship must be seen in their specific context.

Answer (score 0):

It means:

People experiencing either ...

1. their second infection, while being immuno-suppressed

or

2. being around the age of 15

... are qualities that are usually associated [or known to be characteristics of] a patient with dengue-haemorrhagic fever.

*’Or’ in a list of three is a bit confusing but since it precedes the last item in the list, we should choose that as the contrary option to what is before it (one option with a pause, created by a comma).*